# Как удалить файл после скачивания его пользователем?

Tags: php, download

Скачивание файла настроено через jquery, путем передачи ссылки на файл контроллером и перехода по ней в jquery функцией location. Мне нужно удалить файл после того, как он скачался.

Таким образом он выдается PHP в jquery

```
unlink(script_path() . "upload/temp/"  . $import_id . "/" . $sFileName);
echo str_replace('/index.php','/upload/temp/' . $import_id . "/" . $sFileName, site_url());
```

Если оставить unlink то файл удалиться перед тем как начнется скачивание. По сути нужно что то типа ожидания в минуту после начала скачивания, а потом удалять файл (файл не будет весить больше мегабайта).

Я думал сделать ожидание в жквери, но тогда пользователь может закрыть страницу и скрипт прервется.

Comment: а если у пользователя узкий канал и он не успеет скачать файл за 1 минуту?

Comment: А если у пользователя оборвётся интернет или зависнет комп во время скачивания?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6):

Складывайте такие файлы в отдельную папку на сервере. Напишите в `crontab` задачу N раз в день "удалять все файлы из данной папки, если они старше 24 часов", например.

```
find /path/to/temp/files* -mtime +1 -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: Спасибо за идею, возможно попробую реализовать, только опыта общения с линуксом почти нет, но так хочется что бы красиво работало.

Comment: кронтаб - это не страшно, экспериментируйте. главное - не напутайте с путями, что именно удалять.

Comment: @T.Zagidullin крон можно использовать не только в линуксе. Для винды есть программа `CRONw`. На хостах любых есть крон по-умолчанию